# How to replace path stored in variable using sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I've a script

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /home/nnice/Downloads/Images/* /run/media/nnice/New\ Volume/FILES/Softwares/HTTP/Downloads/Images

mv /home/nnice/Downloads/Video/* /run/media/nnice/New\ Volume/FILES/Softwares/HTTP/Downloads/Videos
```

I need to replace path using sed command. I've stored paths in variables

```
replace="/run/media/nnice/New\ Volume/FILES/Softwares/HTTP/Downloads/"
replacewith="/home/nnice/Windows/D/FILES/Softwares/HTTP/Downloads/"
```

I am trying following command but it doesn't work

```
sed -i "s/$replace/$replacewith/g" script.sh
```

I've also used different separators instead of / but script remains unchanged.

```
[nnice@myhost scripts]$ sed  "s|$replace|$replacewith|g" script.sh
#!/bin/bash
mv /home/nnice/Downloads/Images/* /run/media/nnice/New\ Volume/FILES/Softwares/HTTP/Downloads/Images

mv /home/nnice/Downloads/Video/* /run/media/nnice/New\ Volume/FILES/Softwares/HTTP/Downloads/Videos
```

can you please help me with that to replace them using sed command?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your command fails because you're using the same separator for the sed command and your file paths.  File paths need to use `/` but sed separators can be anything, so try this:

```
sed -i "s@$replace@$replacewith@g" script.sh
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering common FAQs. Instead, vote to close as a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: I have tried @ and | as sed separators but It doesn't replaces